# getting extra html code while exporting data to excel using php issue

Tags: php, wordpress, excel, wp-list-categories

I am want to export data to excel sheet from custom table.this table is created from wp_list_table in admin section of wordpress. followed is the code i implemented to fetch the data in excel sheet.

```
     global $wpdb;
      $data ="";
         $values = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT company_name,firstname,email,phone,country FROM (table_name) where id='.$id.' ;',ARRAY_A);
         $header = "Name" . "\t";
        $header .= "Email" . "\t";
        $header .= "Phone" . "\t";
         $header .= "Country" . "\t";

   foreach($values as $line){
   $row1 = array();


   $row1[] = $line['firstname'];
   $row1[] = $line['email'];
  $row1[] = $line['phone'];
   $row1[] = $line['country'];


  $data .= join("\t", $row1)."\n";
   }
   header("Content-type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=expot.xls");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\n$data"; 
    exit();
```

My issue is that on exporting the data whole html of the page is also there in my excel sheet. my excel sheet look like attached image[image]

Please suggest whats wrong in the code. why it is getting whole page html in excel sheet.

Regards
swati